# Unable to guess what crash occurred iOS

Tags: ios, crash

This is the crash report for my app in app store. I am unable to guess what causes the crash. In thread 9, I can see one of the calls from my app, but I don't know whether the crash is related to a system call or anything else.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x30bbdf46 objc_msgSend + 6
    1   CoreFoundation                      0x23362281     __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 13
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x232be52d _CFXNotificationPost + 1785
    3   Foundation                          0x23fee189 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 73
    4   UIKit                               0x268e2009 -[UIApplication _stopDeactivatingForReason:] + 469
    5   UIKit                               0x26ad1949 -[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:] + 2025
    6   UIKit                               0x26ac96bd -[UIApplication workspace:didReceiveActions:] + 81
    7   FrontBoardServices                  0x29af00e9 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 13
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x2337039d __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 13
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x2336f661 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 217
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x2336e19b __CFRunLoopRun + 1715
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x232bc211 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 477
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x232bc023 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x2a66f0a9 GSEventRunModal + 137
    14  UIKit                               0x268c81d1 UIApplicationMain + 1441
    15  My App                              0x0003c6fb main (main.m:16)
    16  libdyld.dylib                       0x31131aaf start + 3

Thread 9:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x311e44f0 mach_msg_trap + 20
    1   CoreFoundation                      0x2336f93b __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 147
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x2336dee1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1017
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x232bc211 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 477
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x232bc023 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
    5   Foundation                          0x23ff3bfd -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 265
    6   Foundation                          0x240420bd -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 81
    7   My App                              0x000f6cef +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:185)
    8   Foundation                          0x240b8b5b __NSThread__main__ + 1119
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x31274e93 _pthread_body + 139
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x31274e07 _pthread_start + 119
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x31272b90 thread_start + 8
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost certainly somebody has registered to receive a notification from the notification centre and been deallocated without unregistering. It looks like it was possibly somebody expecting to receive a notification from `UIApplication`.

Common causes: not calling `removeObserver:` in `dealloc`, or sometimes imagining that a method will be called that isn't. Almost everybody used to get the wrong idea about `viewDidUnload` at first, though it's completely deprecated now, and there are bound to be much more subtle variations.

Check everyone that adds themselves as notification observers.

Comment: My application receiving push notification.Is this may be the reason.